# Why should I get a massage?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In the Galdin Quay restaurant, there is a spa in the back right that allows you to get a massage. Ignis pointed it out and hinted towards getting one, so I tried it out to see what happened. Noctis however did not appear to like it and bolted from the bed.

Why should I get a massage? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: https://www.amtamassage.org/articles/1/News/detail/3124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really is no purpose to getting a massage in Galdin Quay. In fact, the fact that you can even get a massage is listed as trivia in some places. From the [Galdin Quay wikia page](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Galdin_Quay):

> If the player speaks to the masseuse Noctis can get a massage. If the player reads the sign for the spa, his party members suggest they should do it but Noctis will decline.

And from [the IGN walkthrough for The Errand Prince](http://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-15/The_Errand_Prince):

> You can stop in the Galdin Quay outpost itself for food and lodging if you wish - or just talk to the waitress to learn more about the area. Everything here is probably a bit expensive for your level (though you can try for a back massage - even if Noctis isn’t keen on them).

It seems that this scene is merely added for humor, however, it's noted in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/932981-final-fantasy-xv/74761926?page=1) that Prompto will take a picture of the occasion, so that seems to be the *one* thing that will come from it.

> Prompto will even take a pic of it too.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a functional part of the game in any sense so nothing comes of making Noctis get a massage at any time of day or night.

However it's widely believed that the prompt to get a massage is to cue up some of the traditional odd-ball humor / programmer humor (hotdog shortage and "long cat" in FF8, as a brief example) though I can't see a programmer joke in that particular instance.

Perhaps it's just a way to illustrate a degree of humanity - the guy spends the whole game getting knocked around by monsters and can't handle a massage.

Answer (score -1):

In some cutscenes and in the anime (and how weird noctis walks/runs/stands in the game), he got an injury with his back/spine.

Maybe that's why he didn't like massage